# the form get stuck after keyboard hide on Android in Sencha Extjs6.0.2

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, extjs

I have got the problem of scrolling form in sencha-extjs 6. When the keyboard is loading, we can scroll form up/down, but when the keyboard is hided, the form got stuck ( some part hide and some part show ). I got this problem when run on Android Mobile. Could anybody could help?

Comment: With so few information, no. Do you have a link where we can verify the problem with our own mobile devices?

Comment: No, I don't have. @Alexander